# Data not show in view in mvc ajax json jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

data not showing the controller to view using JSON function. I already check using breakpoint controller return 2 value but data do not show in view, can anyone help me where I am wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomer")',
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });

        debugger;
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            var customers = response.d;
            $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).remove();
            $(customers).each(function () {
                $(".MemberID", table).html(this.MemberShipID);
                $(".name", table).html(this.name);
                $(".FName", table).html(this.FName);
                $(".Gender", table).html(this.Gender);
                $(".address", table).html(this.address);
                $(".phone1", table).html(this.phone1);
                $(".mobileno", table).html(this.mobileno);
                $(".email", table).html(this.email);
                $("#dvCustomers").append(table).append("<br />");
                table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: 1. Why are you cloning the table and removing it, just to insert it a bit later? That makes no sense. 
2. You are trying to add data to coloums with a class selector, keep in mind there could more than one element...

Comment: He is getting a response, but he can't display it...

Comment: Yes ,Kris  Your write when i put console.log(response); don't show any thing , but when i write this success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }   show me the array of data.

Comment: Can you give me skype id  igor , i show you to everything you can figure out better,

Comment: Anyone Help me Please

Comment: can you get response in ajax success method?